# Minecraft Keeps crashing everytime I try to load it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Ouch. That hurt :(

Time: 1/3/17 2:57 AM
Description: Initializing game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:247)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at bes.ap(SourceFile:600)
    at bes.an(SourceFile:436)
    at bes.a(SourceFile:383)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)

### A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:

-- Head --
Thread: Client thread
Stacktrace:
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:247)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at bes.ap(SourceFile:600)
    at bes.an(SourceFile:436)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at bes.a(SourceFile:383)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.11.2
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_25, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 50486592 bytes (48 MB) / 151265280 bytes (144 MB) up to 1060372480 bytes (1011 MB)
    JVM Flags: 6 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.11.2
    LWJGL: 2.9.4
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    CPU:

Answer (score -3):

Try reinstalling and updating java, deleting `libraries` folder and updating GPU drivers.